# Do Facebook Test User Access Tokens expire

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was wanting to setup a test case for facebook logins.  Ideally Im looking to use a test user and have their access token never expire.  does it expire?

Comment: I assume it works like any user so it expires

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Test user tokens work the same, **But** there's an api you can easily generate them

Check: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/app/accounts/test-users